ApplicationContext not loading in Junit 4 test case after upgrading to spring-boot v3.2.10
This used to work in spring-boot v2 but after upgrading to spring-boot v3 test case gives error. The @Value annotation is not picking the right value from application.properties file because the ApplicationContext is not loading. Other test cases which do not have @Value annotation are working fine after upgrading to spring-boot v3 but only this test case is failing.
This is the test file
package com.booking.test.efs.config;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RepositoryConfigTest.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:config/application-prod.properties")
public class RepositoryConfigTest {

    private static final int MONTH_TO_LIVE = 36;

    @Value("${efs.dynamodb.business.event.ttl.months}")
    private int beTtl;

    @Test
    public void checkProductionConfigHasRetentionProp() {
        assertEquals(beTtl, MONTH_TO_LIVE);
    }
}

This is the error I get when i run the test case
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v3.2.10)

============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================

Positive matches:
----------------
    None

Negative matches:
-----------------
    None

Exclusions:
-----------
    None

Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None

{"timestamp":"2024-11-14 13:22:12.857","level":"WARN","thread":"Test worker","logger":"org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager","message":"Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] to prepare test instance [com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest@1f72fbd1]","context":"default","exception":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7b0525a8 testClass = com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest, locations = [], classes = [com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [PropertySourceDescriptor[locations=[classpath:config/application-prod.properties], ignoreResourceNotFound=false, name=null, propertySourceFactory=null, encoding=null]], propertySourceProperties = [\"org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true\"], contextCustomizers = [org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@5ac7aa18, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@c27d163, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@325bb9a6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@23e44287, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@14fc5d40, org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer@3afae281, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@eca5d99e], resourceBasePath = \"src/main/webapp\", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)\n\tat org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)\n\tat org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:57)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:39)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)\n\tat org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)\n\tat jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)\n\tat org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)\n\tat org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)\n\tat org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)\n\tat org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)\n\tat worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)\n\tat worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:825)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)\n\tat org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)\n\tat org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)\n\tat org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)\n\t... 43 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)\n\tat java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)\n\tat org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer.customizeContext(SpockContextCustomizer.java:43)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:443)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:627)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:401)\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)\n\t... 52 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)\n\t... 66 common frames omitted\n"}

Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7b0525a8 testClass = com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest, locations = [], classes = [com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [PropertySourceDescriptor[locations=[classpath:config/application-prod.properties], ignoreResourceNotFound=false, name=null, propertySourceFactory=null, encoding=null]], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@5ac7aa18, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@c27d163, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@325bb9a6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@23e44287, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@14fc5d40, org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer@3afae281, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@eca5d99e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@7b0525a8 testClass = com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest, locations = [], classes = [com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [PropertySourceDescriptor[locations=[classpath:config/application-prod.properties], ignoreResourceNotFound=false, name=null, propertySourceFactory=null, encoding=null]], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@5ac7aa18, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@c27d163, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@325bb9a6, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@23e44287, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@14fc5d40, org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer@3afae281, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@eca5d99e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:825)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer.customizeContext(SpockContextCustomizer.java:43)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:443)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:627)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:401)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 66 more


com.booking.test.efs.config.RepositoryConfigTest > checkProductionConfigHasRetentionProp FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at SpringApplication.java:825
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at ClassLoader.java:-2
                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader.java:641
1 test completed, 1 failed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
BUILD FAILED in 14s
7 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 4 up-to-date

These are dependencies of the build.gradle file
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.26.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.0.1-jre'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3-transfer-manager:2.28.0'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced:2.28.0'

    implementation 'io.opentracing.contrib:span-reporter-slf4j'
    implementation 'jaxen:jaxen'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time'
    implementation 'net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:9.9.1-3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.15.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.2'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt'
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver'
    runtimeOnly 'ch.qos.logback:logback-access'

    testImplementation 'com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'com.almworks.sqlite4java:sqlite4java:1.0.392'
    testImplementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-beans'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-context'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-aop'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-context-support'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-test'
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.9'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.1-groovy-3.0'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.1-groovy-3.0'
    testImplementation 'cglib:cglib-nodep'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
    testImplementation 'org.unitils:unitils-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}


You can try adding testImplementation 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine' but better way is to migrate from Junit4 to Junit5

Migrate to JUnit5 or add the junit-vintage-engine and junit4. As another tip remove the org.springframework dependencies, those ar eincluded through the starters already, adding them isn't needed. The same for the com.fasterxml.jackson dependencies they are already present (and you are including old versions anyway). Replace 'org.hibernate.validator with spring-boot-starter-validation.

As per the stacktrace, error seems to be caused by spockframework.
Try upgrading to compatible version of spring boot 3/spring 6 framework.
Try this:
testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.4-M3-groovy-3.0'
testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.4-M4-groovy-3.0'

